# For what wine does not it work well with ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, wine

I alone use wine for 2 things, to use Ares and to use games, when it had ubuntu 11.10 of 32 bits it was using " call of duty 4 modern warfare ", to traverse it did not have any problem, but when I started using ubuntu 12.04 LTS of 64 bits it started spending something strange when it was playing, in a mission of nothing there go out many lines of different colors, points of red color, balls of gray color that are deformed, you illuminate many on the screen when there is fire or smoke, nothing of it was happening to myself when it had ubuntu 11.10, the version of wine is 1.4, what must I do in order that I worked like before?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the latest wine version, use clean wineprefix, set the correct winearch architecture (12.04x64 comes with two wine versions) before wineprefix is created and of course check winehq database.